# AWS Glue & Crawler for Hierarchical Avro file

Tags: amazon-web-services, avro, aws-glue

We have a use case to read Hierarchical Avro file whose Schema would change dynamically during ingestion. I am aware that for flatten file we can use Crawler to read the metadata and create a schema out of it , however I would like to know whether crawler can read the schema out of a Hierarchical file and refresh the Glue ETL job. Please share you thoughts on this.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Glue crawlers can read the hierarchical schema and can be used in Glue job dynamically